# Not removing “OK” button from sweet alert dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert, sweetalert2

As i'm using sweet alert in my project so i'm trying to change button text and add cancel button.
In some pages it works but in some it fails and only shows **OK** fixed, here is my screenshot below.
[image: working]

Its working as seen with **Yes** and **Cancel** button but in other page it shows as follows.

[image: not working]

Here is my code which i'm using below.

```
function DeleteSubscription(CompanySubscriptionId, CompanyId) {
            swal({
                title: "Are you sure?",
                text: ("You want to delete this Subscription !"),
                type: "warning",
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: "#5cb85c",
                confirmButtonText: "Yes",
                closeOnConfirm: false
            })
                .then(function (isConfirm) {
                    if (isConfirm) {
                        
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
        }
```

As on the second image its not showing button as **Yes** and **Cancel** only **OK**.

Comment: You might need to look into css applied nto both pages. There might be some css overwrites, since you are using the same component. Check in the dom if the cancel button and the exclamation marks are there, and if there is any styling applied to it.

Comment: What's the code for the one that works?

Comment: Normally, you use `swal.fire({})` with Sweet alert.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].  The code provided *does not work at all* for SweetAlert2 (as per your tag [sweetalert2]) - it will give `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function` unless you have some other form of wrapper.  The code you've provided looks like syntax for [sweetalert] (not two) which is a completely different library.

Comment: Using your code with latest [sweetalert] gives a *ton* of deprecated errors - and obvious things to your problem such as `"showCancelButton" option has been deprecated.`, so we'll also need to know which version you're using.   Without this, your question is useless and unanswerable (other than: you're mixing your libraries/versions).

Comment: @freedomn-m here is the cdn which i'm using https://unpkg.com/sweetalert@2.1.2/dist/sweetalert.min.js

Comment: So the latest one from [sweetalert] (and **not sweetalert2**) - check your browser console for messages and revisit the website for the latest configuration/options.

Comment: @freedomn-m i have found my solution as it was being twice used. Removed which was being referred in the page.

Answer (score 2):

I added `fire` into Swal, and ran it - Seems like that works fine - It had errors before though - But you have to many closing brackets in your function as well -

Don't you have any console errors?

Using SweetAlert 2

```js
Swal.fire({
                title: "Are you sure?",
                text: ("You want to delete this Subscription !"),
                //type: "warning", -  doesn't exist
                showCancelButton: true,
                 confirmButtonColor: '#d33',
                confirmButtonText: "Yes",
                //closeOnConfirm: false -  doesn't exist
            })
                .then(function (isConfirm) {
                    if (isConfirm) {
                        
                            }
                        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9.17.1/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
```

Using SweetAlert 1, I added comments explaining what is happening

```js
swal({
                    title: "Are you sure?",
                    text: ("You want to delete this Subscription !"),
                    type: "warning", //type and imageUrl have been replaced with a single icon option.
                    icon:'warning', //The right way
                    showCancelButton: true, //showCancelButton and showConfirmButton are no longer needed. Instead, you can set buttons: true to show both buttons, or buttons: false to hide all buttons. By default, only the confirm button is shown.
                    confirmButtonColor: '#d33', //you should specify all stylistic changes through CSS. As a useful shorthand, you can set dangerMode: true to make the confirm button red. Otherwise, you can specify a class in the button object.
                    confirmButtonText: "Yes", // everything is in the buttons argument now
                    closeOnConfirm: false,
                    buttons:true,//The right way
                    buttons: ["No", "Yes"] //The right way to do it in Swal1
                })
                    .then(function (isConfirm) {
                        if (isConfirm) {
                            
                                }
                            });
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ah - I see now, that you might be using SweetAlert 1....

Comment: Found my solution as it was being twice called. Thank you for the answer also.

Comment: I give u my thumbs up anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you missing some parameter, check the doc: https://sweetalert2.github.io/#examples

```js
Swal.fire({
    title: "Are you sure?",
    text: ("You want to delete this Subscription !"),
    //type: "warning", -  doesn't exist
    showCancelButton: true,
     showCloseButton: true, // optional
     showConfirmButton: true, // optional
    confirmButtonColor: '#d33',
    confirmButtonText: "Yes",
    //closeOnConfirm: false -  doesn't exist
  })
  .then(function(isConfirm) {
    if (isConfirm) {

    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9.17.1/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Found my solution as it was being twice called. Thank you for the answer also.